# the new template doesn't work well

Tags: templates, lyx-layouts

I was going crazy with the LyX and MikTeX configuration for a new class,I think I have done it matching the step! but None I get

here what i've done:

> Get a copy of the class file, and copy
>   it into a folder with the same name
>   into
>   `C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.8\tex\latex.`
>   So, for `ociamthesis.cls`, you should
>   have a folder called `ociamthesis`
>   within
>   `C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.8\tex\latex`.
>   This is Windows Vista / Windows 7
>   specific, you will soon see why…
>   Create a new file and paste the
>   following into it:

```
% Do not delete the line below; configure depends on this
 \DeclareLaTeXClass[xxx]{article (xxx)}
 Input general definitions
```

> Input `stdclass.inc` replacing xxx
>   with the class name (without the .cls
>   extension).

In my case, xxx is `eethesis`, and the code above becomes:

```
% Do not delete the line below; configure depends on this
 \DeclareLaTeXClass[ociamthesis]{report (ociamthesis)}
 Input general definitions
 Input stdclass.inc
```

Thanks goes out to [Adding a new class in LyX](http://wastedmonkeys.com/2007/09/27/adding-a-new-class-in-lyx-windows) for this.

> Save this file to `C:\Program
>   Files\LyX16\Resources\layouts`, naming
>   it `ociamthesis.layout`. In a command
>   prompt (type cmd in start menu), type
>   texhash. What you will now see it
>   doing is iterating through several
>   folders for new classes, one of which
>   (`C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.8\`)
>   is where we copied the ociamthesis.cls
>   class file into.
>       Within Lyx, hit Tools > Reconfigure, then restart Lyx.

but when I try to run, I get this error message : LaTeX Error :

```
File 'ociamthesis.sty' not found
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Lyx (and looking at your complicated description I'm quite grateful ;-)) but two remarks:

1. you add a `.cls` file while your error message miss a `.sty`. If you quoted the error message correctly, your lyx configuration is probably wrong.
2. If the error message actually says that the `cls` is not found then either your root (`C:\User\...\2.8`) is either not a known root of miktex or you didn't update its FNDB. Check in miktex settings if the root is listed (check "show miktex roots) and update the FNDB. If you have a multiuser setup do it in user and admin mode.

Comment: I run MikteX as Admin, the roots are C:\ProgramData\MikTeX\2.8 and C:\Program Files\MikTeX2.8
but when I run it as user, the roots are C:\Users\win7\AppData\Roaming\MikTeX\2.8 and C:\Users\win7\AppData\Local\MikTeX\2.8 beside the two above. so there are 4 root of MikTeX if I run it as user.
yes, I've done All of your suggestion, but I still get the same error message??

Comment: You didn't say if your error message actually miss a .sty or .cls. I can't help you if you got the lyx part wrong. But to test the miktex part: Make with an editor a small latex document `test.tex` which starts with `\documentclass{ociamthesis}` and compile it on the command line with `latex test`. If `ociamthesis.cls` is found the miktex part is ok.

Comment: thanks Ulrike, I found my mistake, some packages in ociamthesis not yet instal in my MiKTeX, now the template is running well, but I get new problem, althought it's running well but the new environments I've define and create in ociamthesis can't appear in the lyx dropdown menu environment. do you know why ?

Comment: No. As I said: I'm not using lyx.